# Firebase prevent duplicate categories using rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Here is my database structure for **categories**

[image]

I want prevent duplicate data using **Firebase rules**

here is my firebase rule

```
 {
    "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",


    "categories": {
      "$catid": {

       ".validate": "!root.child(newData.child('type').val()).exists()"
      }
    }
} 
}
```

When I am trying to insert again **java** it's inserting duplicate of **java**

how do I prevent to insert duplicate category

Comment: my question is similar to this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/_2YQ--nmTzw

Comment: And the recommendation there is the same: you cannot ensure unique values with security rules. Only unique keys.

Comment: thanks i have update my data structure and it's working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per suggested by [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)

I have changed my data structure as following

[image]

and also updated **Firebase rules** as following

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "auth != null",

 "categories": {
   "$categorie":{
        ".validate": "!data.exists()"
   }
 }
}
}
```

Now it's not inserting data if data is already there.

Thanks [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)