# Check if firebase child has a specific value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a app chat based on firebase database and I want to know if a particular value is already stored.

[image: Database structure]

According to the above structure how can I prevent two equal values ​​(in red) from being inserted into the same child (blue)?

**EDIT**

I solved this problem as follows:
1) I changed the push values ​​of each node by unique username;
2) I checked the duplicate values ​​with the code below:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("friend").child(value_in_blue)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(username)) {
                    //value does not exists
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Thank you  Frank van Puffelen and Jins Lukose for giving me guidance on this issue.

Comment: There is no atomic way to prevent duplicate **values** in a tree. The solution is typically to have an additional data structure where the values are used as the keys, because the child keys in a node are by definition guaranteed to be unique. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39912201, https://stackoverflow.com/a/25328654, https://stackoverflow.com/a/20291163, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244705

Answer (score 2):

Firebase provides **hasChild()** method to check value for child exist or not for pirticuler child. You can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24824732/test-if-a-data-exist-in-firebase) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
fdbRefer.child("give your value").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
if(dataSnapshot.exist() {
//comes here if exit
}
else {
//if not exist
}
}
});
```

Comment: This prevents any value from being inserted!

Comment: @afazolo before inserting next value use this. i have used this same in a project

Comment: Okay. But once I enter a value I can not insert another one!

Comment: @afazolo i think you have some logic mistake

Comment: Maybe. I'll do some more testing with your approach. Thank you.

Comment: I've tried using FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(idFriend), where idFriend is the value in red of my question, with no success. Should I try .child("friend"/ + idFriend)?